# How does auto-login Outlook successfully when in AD environment?

Tags: python, ldap

When I logon to my company's computer with the AD username/password, I find that my Outlook will launch successfully. That means the AD authentication has passed.

In my opinion, outlook retrieves the AD user information, then sends it to an LDAP server to verify.

But I don't know how it retrieves the information, or by some other methods?

Comment: what does you question have to do with python?

Comment: Oh, I just want to realize the method by Python Language

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is an ongoing communication between your workstation and the Active Directory server, which can use LDAP protocol.
Since I don't know what you tried so far, I suggest that you look into the python module `python-ldap`. I have used it in the past to connect, query and modify information on Active-Directory servers.

Comment: Thanks, the python-ldap module need user to input the username/password firstly as the document described, but what I need is that when I have logined the AD domain, there is a way to pass the authentication process directly, don't have to input the password